# bundle size for an angular project?

Tags: angular, optimization, angular-cli

I work on an anuglar project using angular-cli.
The generated main.bundle size is about 4.32 MB in dev mode.

[image: bundle dev]

below th bundle size generated for production with the folowing cmd:

```
ng build --target=production --environment=prod
```

[image: bundle prod]

The size of all requests in prod mode is about 2.5MB.
[image: firebug network]

Is it an accepeted size for a project with few dependencies, modules and components?

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

**aot compilation fails with the folowing stacktrace:

```
>ng build --prod --aot
  0% compilingthis._directiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate is not a function
TypeError: this._directiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate is not a function
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14493:60)
    at C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14644:50
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadNgModuleMetadata (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14634:56)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleMetadata (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14566:31)
    at addNgModule (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12915:37)
    at C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12929:16
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _loadNgModules (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12928:28)
    at analyzeNgModules (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12685:14)
    at OfflineCompiler.compileModules (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12744:18)
    at CodeGenerator.codegen (C:\Users\iminar\Dev\angular\modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.ts:71:26)
    at AotPlugin._make (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:186:43)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:151:75)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsParallel (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:156:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:463:8)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:73:70)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:456:7)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:219:10)
    at Compiler.readRecords (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:367:10)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:216:9)
    at next (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:81:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\CachePlugin.js:34:58)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:85:13)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:213:8)
    at next (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:81:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\node\NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js:23:3)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:85:13)
    at Compiler.run (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:210:7)
    at C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\build-webpack.js:26:29
    at initializePromise (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\es6-promise\dist\lib\es6-promise\-internal.js:244:5)
    at new Promise (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\es6-promise\dist\lib\es6-promise\promise.js:135:31)
    at Class.exports.default.Task.extend.run (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\build-webpack.js:25:16)
    at Class.Command.extend.run (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\build.js:50:26)
    at Class.<anonymous> (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\models\command.js:152:17)
    at tryCatch (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\rsvp\dist\lib\rsvp\-internal.js:215:12)
    at invokeCallback (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\rsvp\dist\lib\rsvp\-internal.js:230:13)
    at C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\rsvp\dist\lib\rsvp\then.js:29:16
    at flush (C:\dev\clients\cf\projects\op\frontend\node_modules\rsvp\dist\lib\rsvp\asap.js:85:5)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

**Actvating compression on tomcat reduce the data sent to client:
[image: network gzip enabled]

Comment: Yea, that's normal. You can get even smaller with AoT compilation (command `ng build --prod --aot`) if it works for you. And if your server supports gzip you'll send much less over the wire. For example when I run dev server with `compression` middleware bunle size is 2.1MB, which is 335KB with gzip...

Comment: I will try if aot compilation works and gzip config for tomcat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes its look good.

if you want to reduce your app size you can do following things:

1. Divide your app in sub modules and use lazy loading.
2. use AoT compilation mechanism, this will compile your code than you are deploying your runnable code and in JIT(just in time) compilation mechanism code get compiled in user's browser.
3. you can apply gzip and minify your files.

these steps will help you a lot in reducing your app size.

Comment: the app is already divided in modules and I'm using lazy loading. I will try if aot compilation works for me.

Comment: yes try AoT and gzip and minification also. it will help you.

Comment: one question are you using any external css in header of html? or fonts?

Comment: No css files in index.html, I have only 3 js files, I will combine and  minify this files.

Comment: aot compilation failed but activating compression on tomcat was helpful, thank you for this answer.

Comment: AOT should work, bcz AOT Angular 2 providing for precompilation it should work. i think may be you have done something wrong in AOT process. bcz AOT will reduce more size. if you satisfied with result than its okay.

Comment: I got an exception when running the command, see my edit answer.

Comment: have you made changes in tsconfig-aot.json, main.ts, in bootstrap method follow the official doc for Aot https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile. after doing all the steps i think you will resolve your error.

Comment: plz follow whole article.